# SImplifying if statements

Tags: vba, if-statement, simplify

I'm making a VBA-project and want to simplify the following if-statements, because i need to this following 11 times more, for each person.

```
'CTK opportunities
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton1 = True Then Range("B4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton2 = True Then Range("C4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton3 = True Then Range("D4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton4 = True Then Range("E4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton5 = True Then Range("F4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton6 = True Then Range("G4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton7 = True Then Range("H4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton8 = True Then Range("I4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton9 = True Then Range("J4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton10 = True Then Range("K4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton11 = True Then Range("L4").Value = "X"
If result = "CTK" And ToggleButton12 = True Then Range("M4").Value = "X"

'Next person
```

Comment: You can nest everything inside `If result = "CTK" Then`, rather than repeating it so many times

Comment: Are the toggle buttons on a worksheet or a form?  **"11 times more, for each person"** do you mean that there are 11 more people or 11 more toggle buttons?  How does the target range continue for the next person?  Like this `ToggleButton1 = True Then Range("B5").Value = "X"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
Dim ctrl As Control

If result = "CTK" Then
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If InStr(ctrl.Name, "ToggleButton") > 0 Then
            If ctrl.Value Then Cells(4, CInt(Replace(ctrl.Name, "ToggleButton", "")) + 1).Value = "X"
        End If
    Next ctrl
End If
```

Comment: it works with "CTK", but how do i repeat it with fx "MogM"? - and in short terms, how does it work? :-) - But thank you so much, so far.

Comment: 1) as for the _"how does it work?"_ part: it loops through all userform controls (`For Each ctrl In Me.Controls`) and if the current one has "ToggleButton" in its name (`If InStr(ctrl.Name, "ToggleButton") > 0` if its value `True` (`If ctrl.Value`) then cell in row 4 and column corresponding to ToggleButton number plus one is accessed and its value is being set to "X".

Comment: it'd be highly educative you stepped through the code by placing a breakpoint in some statement (place the cursor within that statement and press F9) and then pressing F8 to step to each subsequent statement to be executed and using Immediate Window (CTRL+G to pop it out)  to query relevant variables values (e.g. type `?ctrl.Name` and press return to see the current value);   2) As for the _"how do i repeat it with fx "MogM"?"_ you simply substitute "CTK" with "MogM". If you're looking for handling different _result_ values you may want to use a `Select Case` construct.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to factorizing the test on `"CTK"`, you can also define an array for your ToggleButtons and iterate on it:

```
toggleButtons = Array(ToggleButton1, ToggleButton2, .... , ToggleButton12)

If(result = CTK) Then
    For i = 0 to UBound(toggleButtons)
        If toggleButtons[i] = True Then Cells(4, i+2).Value = "X"
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If result = "CTK" Then
    If ToggleButton1 = True Then
        Range("B4").Value= "X"
    ElseIf ToggleButton2 = True Then
        Range("C4").Value = "X"
    ElseIf...........etc
```

Comment: Wow @A.S.H that's way to complicated for a noob like me, but i'll look into it. How do the code determine, on wich togglebutton are related to a certain cell? :) - and thx for the help btw.